# Handwriting on Mathematica Linux

Tags: linux, input

I saw this wonderful article on [handwriting in Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/HandwrittenMathRecognition.html) and I wanted to ask if it is possible to have similar functionality on Linux.

Comment: The article you link to describes how to use a special feature of Windows with Mathematica.  It describes a Windows feature, not a Mathematica one.  The handwriting recognition is not done by Mathematica itself. Thus what you are looking for is some software that can convert handwriting to MathML (which is needed for interoperability with Mathematica).  This is an interesting question, but it's essentially unrelated to Mathematica, which makes it not a good fit for this site, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not concern Mathematica. It is instead asking for software that can do handwriting recognition on mathematical formulae.

Comment: It seems like a Mathematica-related question for which the answer is "No".  There are handwriting-recognition programs for linux-based tablets, but it seems that Wolfram hasn't taken the step to integrate them with Mathematica.

Comment: Interesting: I have found the handwriting input application in Windows tools, but how can I tell MMA to make this available for Input?

Comment: @JasonB If there's handwriting recognition *that supports math* for Linux, then the answer is not "no". How to integrate a given input software with Mathematica would make a good on-topic question. "What software supports math handwriting recognition" is not really on-topic in my opinion.

Comment: @Szabolcs, that is a good point.  So this question, which asks "is possible to have similar functionality on Linux," is not off-topic - which was all I wanted to say.